# Are there any issues with running a VPS with multiple public ip addresses: one serving a website and mail server; and the other a VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, routing-table, source-routing

I was told that there could be issues running a VPS which has 2 different public ip addresses; one ip running a webpage and mail server; and the other running a vpn.

Right now, I already have everything set up and it all seems to be working just fine: webpage, mail server and VPN.

Are there any concerns I should be aware of with this set up?

Are there any security risks using this VPN if I did want to stay "anonymous"? My website is in the DNS servers, but again, uses a different ip address from my vpn ip.

I was told that to do this correctly would involve setting up source routing, but am having trouble understanding why this is the case.

I am not trying to run the website or mail server through the vpn or anything like that. So I don't understand why the packets would potentially "go down the wrong path".

Is it important that I have a separate routing table for my VPN?

I'm not a networking expert so maybe I am just misunderstanding. Any info would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it a bad idea to run a vpn from the same server which is serving a website?](https://superuser.com/questions/1585305/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-run-a-vpn-from-the-same-server-which-is-serving-a-website)

Comment: Asking the same question multiple times on this forum is not cool. Please don't do it.

Comment: I didn't want to bother you anymore, and was trying to make the question more detailed to get more info. I'm still very unclear about what you were trying to tell me.. Did you think I was trying to route the website through the vpn? Your original response was not answering my question at all and I thought you might have misunderstood. If you're willing to explain further, I would really appreciate it. @davidgo

Comment: I'm also guessing that is the case here, because source-specific routing should only become necessary if your server connects to a VPN provided by someone else, but not when it hosts its own VPN.

Comment: Also, at the time I did not have anything set up, but now that I have everything working, I'm even more curious because everything seems fine. Are there any test I can try to determine if the packets are "going down the wrong path"? A packet would know where the next hop is because it asks the dns server for the site that I requested, right? How does my webpage interfere with that process? @davidgo

Comment: @user1686 yeah, my server isn't connecting to a vpn, it is the vpn server. Are you guessing that it is or isn't important to have a dedicated routing table in this case? I'm only using my vpn for my personal browsing. It is not rerouting the traffic to my site or email server.